# phonegap version 4.3 splashscreen doesn't show

Tags: cordova

I'm using cli and I installed the splashscreen plugin (cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen). Then I added the following lines to config.xml (images exist in that folders):

```
<platform name="android">
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

but when I run the project, splashscreen doesn't show. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the folder you are pointing at is incorrect.  The locations start in the project's root.  Here is a snippet from my config.xml where I placed the splash screens in www/ due to the way BB10 handles the splash screen locations:

```
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-200x320.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-320x480.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-480x800.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-720x1280.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-320x200.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-480x320.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-800x480.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="www/assets/splash/Android/splash-1280x720.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
```

However, you are missing that preference with `value="screen"` and I believe that is your real issue.  This will clobber the name of your file when it is copied over during the build. For example `www/assets/splash/Android/splash-200x320.png` will become `platforms/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png`.

You can verify this by looking in the `platforms/android/res/`.  If nothing exists then it might be one of these two reasons I have listed here.