# Responsive web app as a phonegap packaged mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

My requirement is pretty simple. I have a responsive web -url, and I want to package it as an android app, so that whenever the app is accessed the web-url will open in device native browser, and for the user it will behave as a mobile app.
I am using below config.xml for my phonegap build:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.demo.sample" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        Sample.in mobile app.
    </description>
    <author email="@#$%@gmail.com" href="http://google.in">
        Team
    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <content src="http://google.in/" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
    <icon src="icon/android/playstore-icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="icon/android/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="icon/android/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="icon/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="icon/android/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="icon/android/loading-image.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>    
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>   
</widget>
```

When I package this app, the splash screen is not visible while loading app on android. Any suggestions as what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm `icon/android/loading-image.png`'s location?  This should be in your root folder.  Other than that, at a quick glance this looks alright.  Confirm your images are being copied over by checking the platform/android/res folder.  I posted an excerpt from one of my projects here, it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853697/phonegap-version-4-3-splashscreen-doesnt-show/28862545#28862545

Comment: @laughingpine :By root forder you mean inside www folder?

Comment: The project root meaning the folder above `www/`  If you are using `www/ `then change your path to: `www/icon/android/loading-image.png` -- the exception being BlackBerry, which must pull from the `www/` folder

Comment: @laughingpine : It's still not working. I have checked everything you mentioned.

Comment: l am not as familiar with phonegap, but their syntax is supposedly different, for example  `<gap:splash src="ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />`  Apologies, my comments were targeting plain Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a work around rather than trying to include it from the config file , can you try copy pasting your splash and icon images in `platform/android/res/drawable` according that might just work

Answer (score 0):

@user4905013,
The title to your post has nothing to do with your issue. I almost did not read it. You should have the title be about your issue or question.

I have demo Apps working where you can see the source code.
You want *Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test*

http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html

Best of Luck
Jesse